# jQueryUI datepicker widget add 'onClose' function after widget initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Let's say I have a #date field. At first I initialize it with some options (they are not important at the moment):

```
$('#date').datepicker(options);
```

Then, if I try to add `onClose` function, I would do:

```
$('#date').datepicker({onClose: function(dateText, inst){console.log("Hello World");}});
```

Howerver, this overrides options set before. Let's say I don't have access to these options - datepicker is initialized, options are set and now I need to add function `onClose`. How to do that? I've tried `.datepicker('option','onClose',function(){});` with no effect.

Comment: You should initialize the `datepicker` on an id only once. If you are doing multiple times the latter will override the first options. Is that what is happening?

Comment: Yes. That's why I need another way to add 'onClose' function.

Answer (score 6):

Try it as

```
$('#date').datepicker( 'option' , 'onClose', function() {} );
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$('#date').datepicker();
...
$('#date').datepicker("option", {
  onClose: function(dateText, inst){console.log("Hello World");}
});
```

Of course this would override the previous onClose function you've set before.
source: [jQuery forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/datepicker-bind-onclose-event-during-runtime#14737000002669091)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#date').datepicker().bind('onClose',function(){
    console.log("Hello World");
});
```

Comment: Actually, this is the closest solution. I've modified my options, so that they trigger events, like:
`onClose: function(dateText,inst){$(this).trigger("date_closed",[dateText, inst]}`
And then I can use this trigger wherever I want:
`$('#date').on('date_closed',function(dateText, inst){});`
Not too neat, but fulfills my needs :)

Comment: Maybe it was downvoted because ['bind' is deprecated in favour of 'on'](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and because the datepicker has [an option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option) which is intended for this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Define your on-close function as just one of your options, in the initialisation. This works for me.

```
$('#date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onClose: function(dateText, inst){console.log("Hello World");}
});
```

Comment: Not during initialization: the OP wants to do it after initialization (e.g. using [the option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option)).

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue that older close function was getting replaced. 
After searching a lot and I have implement my own function to deal with this issue. Below is the code snippet

```
function addCloseFunctionToDatePicker(id, funHandler) {
    var $datePicker=$('#' + id);
    var prevhandler = $datePicker.datepicker('option', 'onClose');
    $datePicker.datepicker('option', {
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {                    
            if (prevhandler) {
                prevhandler(dateText, inst);
            }
           funHandler(dateText, inst);                
        }            
    });    
}
```

Calling mechanism :

```
 addCloseFunctionToDatePicker('myDatePicker', function(){ alert("I'm next method"); });
```